# The link to a subtitled version or the link for a subtitles version?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was writting a post on Facebook and I didn't know how to write this properly:

-This is the link to a subtitled version

or

-This is the link for a subtitled version

A few months ago a modern languages professor told me that "for" was for nouns and "to" for verbs, so I think that the first sentence is good, but also the second one seems ok, would you help me please?

Comment: The link is to a resource. It is for your recipient.

Comment: By the way, there's a typo in the title, and I thought the question was about that at first. Also, your last sentence seems the wrong way round.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the official version:

> ### 4.8. Links
>
> **4.8.1. Introduction**
>
> Links are a conceptual construct, created by `<a>`, `<area>`, and `<link>`
>   elements, that represent a connection between two resources, one of
>   which is the current `Document`. There are two kinds of links in HTML:
>
> **Links to external resources**
>       These are links to resources that are to be used to augment the current document, generally automatically processed by the user agent.
>
> **Hyperlinks**
>       These are links to other resources that are generally exposed to the user by the user agent so that the user can cause the user agent
>   to navigate to those resources, e.g., to visit them in a browser or
>   download them.
>
> -- *[HTML 5.2 W3C Recommendation, 14 December 2017](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/links.html#links-introduction)*

And also:

> **link**
>   1.4 *Computing* A code or instruction which connects one part of a program or an element in a list to another.
>
> *Do you want to know the best way to obtain inbound links to your web site?*
>   *You may republish if you include an active link to the original and leave this notice in place.*
>   *Sorry I can't post a direct link to any direct article.*
>   -- *[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/link)*

Comment: This answer would be much more powerful if it only had one sentence with "to"

Comment: Program documentation isn’t a particularly good authority for English grammar. The dictionary entry is better, but I don’t see an explanation of why “to” works better than “for” in the OP’s context.

Comment: @Lawrence The HTML specification is not "program documentation". It's the official source of the terminology.

Comment: I don't disagree with your conclusion; it's the justification I'd prefer was more robust. While the spec may define its own terminology, "link to" is a lot more generic in English than just HTML. One can have links to ancestors; ideas or words can jog a memory that links one to particular documents (even *subtitled versions*). This answer would have been fine on an HTML Q&A. I don't think it covers the generality of the *English* words on EL&U.

Answer (score -2):

The first one is correct - you could also write "**here** is the link to a subtitled version" depending on context.

Comment: This looks promising, but I’d like to see more explanation of *why* ‘to’ works better than ‘for’ in the OP’s context.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that "to" is used for destinations thus "This is the train to New York" rather than "This is the train for New York" - this situation seems the same.